# Unity Как жёстко задать угол поворота (не сместить значения имен о жёстко указать например X = 10 градусов)

Tags: unity3d, rotation

Я поворот источника света нахожу в ручную и каждый кадр я знаю на сколько по x y z он должен быть повёрнут в градусах. Но используя функцию
DirectLight.transform.Rotate(10,10,45);
Источник вместо тог чтоб встать в заданную позицию поворота. Смещается относительно текущего поворота, 
а в LOOP будит вообще без устно вращаться.

DirectLight.transform.rotation = new Quaternion(10,10,45,1);
Занимает не правильную позицию в градусах

Как мне указать в градусах как в этом кадре должен быть повёрнут источник?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для указания поворота в градусах используется

```
gameObject.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0 ,0);
gameObject.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0 ,0);
```